# BlockJoin Query in lucene

Tags: lucene, indexing

Can anyone elaborate about BlockJoinQuery in lucene with a simple scenario and source code? I couldnt find any fruitful links from Google for BlockJoinQuery. Any links which will detail about this will be useful for me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just made a blog post about this:

```
http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2012/01/searching-relational-content-with.html
```